# How to convert type numeric to integer

Tags: ejb

The field of my database it contains integer, but it refuses to recover me in numerique

Here is my code to convert numeric to int

t.setAnne(Integer.parseInt(""+cell.getNumericCellValue()));

Comment: it should be `java.math.BigDecimal`

Comment: Integer.parseInt accepts sting representations of integer numbers. Why the addition of `'"'` in the `parseInt` function param?